# Is the LRU cache expunge policy of nginx persistent across reboots?

Tags: nginx, cache

In the doc it says"

> max sets the maximum number of elements in the cache; on cache
>   overflow the least recently used (LRU) elements are removed;

Is it persistent across reboots of nginx or the server?

I wonder how this is tracked? In memory? Or maby using the last access timestamp of the file system?

I cannot find any info on that.

How is the info if the LRU file cannot be determined (because of a reboot)

Edit:

I am aware of the nginx cache loader process. If it was not for that process, cache files would not be persistent at all.

As per documentation this loading process also includes the metadata, not being more specific about what metadata is.

The question is, does this metadata also include the last access timestamp.

However: In order for it to be contained, it must be written first.

I set up an inotifywait on a file and requested it. This is what the HTTP request to a cache file results to:

```
cache-filename OPEN 
cache-filename ACCESS 
cache-filename CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE
```

There appears to occur no modification of the file, this leads to the preliminary conclusion, that the LRU data is not written to disk, and thus not persistent.

But: The data could still be written elsewhere. It could also be written from ram to disk (to the cache fies) by a another process later. So data is persistent, just not guaranteed to be up to date on the disk.

Which still leaves the question unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that nginx may use the access time on the file to indicate what to LRU.  Inspecting the atime across a fleet of servers, some of which are partitioned with smaller caches than others due to other disk usage, it appears that servers with smaller caches and more LRU pressure have no files over a certain age as measured by atime (-amin in find).  The command I used to see this is:

```
for i in `seq 1000 100 4000`; do 
    echo -n "Files accessed more than $i minutes ago: "
    find /opt/nginx-cache/data -type f -amin +$i | wc -l
done
```

And the output from one of our servers:

```
Files accessed more than 1000 minutes ago: 52154
Files accessed more than 1100 minutes ago: 40582
Files accessed more than 1200 minutes ago: 25527
Files accessed more than 1300 minutes ago: 19567
Files accessed more than 1400 minutes ago: 13384
Files accessed more than 1500 minutes ago: 7683
Files accessed more than 1600 minutes ago: 4597
Files accessed more than 1700 minutes ago: 3038
Files accessed more than 1800 minutes ago: 1916
Files accessed more than 1900 minutes ago: 1251
Files accessed more than 2000 minutes ago: 837
Files accessed more than 2100 minutes ago: 585
Files accessed more than 2200 minutes ago: 459
Files accessed more than 2300 minutes ago: 365
Files accessed more than 2400 minutes ago: 258
Files accessed more than 2500 minutes ago: 101
Files accessed more than 2600 minutes ago: 8
Files accessed more than 2700 minutes ago: 0
Files accessed more than 2800 minutes ago: 0
Files accessed more than 2900 minutes ago: 0
Files accessed more than 3000 minutes ago: 0
```

If this is correct, then the cache loader likely reads the atime of the files upon reboot to correctly delete the LRU files as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This document http://czerasz.com/2015/03/30/nginx-caching-tutorial/ describes that there is a process called "Cache loader". It runs only once (on startup) and loads the metadata into the memory zone. It runs in iterations until all keys are loaded.

Comment: I am aware of the cache loader. The page does not answer the question hwoever. Please see the edit to my question for further information.